# solve linear equations with 3 variables that is given by user

Tags: java

i'm trying to figure out how to write down a program in java to solve 2 equations that have 3 variables, which is given by the user:

```
A11 * X1 + A12 * X2 = B1
A21 * X1 + A22 * X2 = B2
```

numbers are given by user, per say 1 2 3 4 5 6 (for a11 a12 a21 a22 b1 b2)
and the answers are "no solution" "many solutions" "single solution (x1,x2)
i'm stuck.... don't even know where to begin
help?

Comment: java != javascript.  You should pick one.

Comment: Do you want the general solution using matrices or a simple solution for two variables?

Comment: You can use int array where the array index will indicate the power of X and array element will be the coefficient of X.

Answer (score 1):

You will get

- no solution when the first equation contradicts the second equation.
- a single solution when the first and second equations are not the same,  or a multiple of each other. i.e. it is solvable.
- multiple solutions if one is a multiple of the other.

---

The general solution is to use matrices.

```
[A11 A12][X1] = [B1]
[A21 A22][X2]   [B2]
```

can be written as

A * X = B

or

X = A<sup>-1</sup> * B

Calculate the inverse of A and multiply it by B and you will have the solution for X.

Comment: it's homework, yes - and i know what you mean by figuring out what the solution will become, i just have no idea what should i use writing a javascript to solve it (when someone writes down the variables..)